# Adjust height of Colorbox

Tags: colorbox

Hello I am looking to improve the equality of these colorboxes. You can see the difference in the dimensions of the shading. I tried the `\strut` command but it changed the table too much. This is the best I could do. Please help in finding a  solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\[ \begin{tabular}{c|c}
\hline
\textbf{Factors of}\ \color{blue}{$\mathbf{6}$}\color{black}{} & \textbf{Sum 
of Factors}\\ \hline
$1,6$ & $7$ \\ \hline
${\setlength{\fboxsep}{1.5pt}\colorbox{brown!50!white}{2,3}}$ &  
${\setlength{\fboxsep}{1.5pt}\colorbox{brown!50!white}{6}}$ \\ \hline 
\end{tabular} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you add a `\vphantom{,}` in the second you will have the same dimensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your problem is solved by [koleygr's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/120578/koleygr) comment, so i add some off-topic suggestion for your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}

\begin{document}
\[ \setlength{\fboxsep}{1.5pt}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
    \hline
\textbf{Factors of \textcolor{blue}{6}} 
        & \textbf{Sum of Factors}                   \\ 
    \hline
1,6     &   7                                       \\ 
    \hline
\colorbox{brown!50!white}{2,3}  
        & \colorbox{brown!50!white}{5\vphantom{,}}  \\  % <--- as suggested koleygr
    \hline
\end{tabular} 
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]